# Problems coding an APDU command to verify PIN

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I'm trying to send a VERIFY (pin) command using `javax.smartcardio` API. My Pin code is 12345678.

Based on some examples I've found on the net, I've tried with this APDU:

```
00 20 00 83 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
```

but the result is:
`69 84 (reference data invalid)`.

I've tried also with:

```
00 20 00 83 08 12 34 56 78
```

But I still get the same error.

According to my SmartCart specifications, the card has support for:

- ISO 7816 smart cards type A, B and C (5 V, 3 V, 1.8 V)
- Compatible    with communication protocols T=0, T=1
- Support for PPS (Protocol and Parameters Selection)

I'm a bit desperate as I cannot find a way out. Can you suggest me some changes to my APDU or even a completely different approach (another library or language to connect with my Smart Card)?

Comment: Changed from "invalidated" to "invalid" and some formatting. That card specification is very general, in itself it doesn't say anything about how the PIN is handled, other than that it will *probably* use the `VERIFY` command for it. The fifth byte is the length of the command data (PIN), so your second try is obviously invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your card is ISO 7816, please refer the APDU from the following [link](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap6_12) section 6.12.

What you need to do is:

1. Check the reference data (P2) that is used. For PIN, usually it is '01' or '81'. But again, check the correct one from your card supplier.
2. Before doing the actual VERIFY command, try to get the remaining tries first. This will help you from locking the PIN, because each false verification reduce your remaining tries. This can be done by setting the Lc = '00' and remove your command data. The response is SW1='63' and SW2='CX', where X denotes the remaining tries. APDU command example: `00 20 00 81 00`
3. You need to convert your PIN into ASCII hex bytes. Therefore, if your PIN is 12345678 then the APDU is `00 20 00 81 08 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Well I've found that sending a 00 20 00 83 00 produces as result "63 CF" and as return string "Non-volatile memory changed". Seems one step forward. However trying the PIN with 00 20 00 83 08 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 still returns ": 69 84 "Reference data invalidated" .
Can I assume that at least I've guessed the correct reference data (P2) ? Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot assume that. Actually, it's a pretty good indication that it is *not* correct. And - in this case important - it is "Reference data invalid" not "Reference data invalidated".

Comment: Thanks. Well the P2 reference data is not exposed by the card supplier so my only chance is to guess it with some lines of code looping from 00 to 99. Hopefully I'll find something.

Comment: @user2824073: Actually the sensible ranges are 0x01..0x1F and 0x81.. 0x9F.

Comment: Thanks a lot I've made it the correct value was 0x90. I've one more question but I'll open a separate thread for it.