# What's wrong with this Verify APDU command?

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I've got the following Verify (PIN) APDU command, that we send to the Gemalto SafeNet Reader K1100:

`00 20 00 81 08 26 12 34 56 ff ff ff ff`

I always get the response `67 00` (wrong length). As far as I know this means that either LC or LE is incorrect.

Comment: What card are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156248/problems-coding-an-apdu-command-to-verify-pin

Comment: It's an a.sign RK CHIP with certificate (https://www.a-trust.at/webshop/Detail.aspx?ProdId=2021)

Answer (score 0):

The APDU looks correct assuming:

- there exists a PIN with ID 1 within the current DF
- the card uses a BCD format for PINs and pads them to 8 bytes **or** the PIN value contains strange non-printable characters

You could try 01 instead of 81, to ensure the PIN is searched in the MF, or 00 assuming the card knows the PIN id implicitly. If both attempts fail, you have to collect more information concerning initialization/personalization of your card.

Since the Verify command has no result, LE can't be wrong. Note however, that when using Java classes to construct the APDU, LC is added automatically and must not be specified.

My only other idea is, to omit the FF bytes adjusting the LC accordingly.

Comment: The card works in another reader with exactly the same command. I always thought that the reader only forwards these commands to the smart card. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChristophWimberger: In principle yes, but for dumb cards (e. g. memory cards) or very smart readers (e.g. replacing PIN data by something entered on the PIN-pad of the reader) modifications by the reader are *necessary*. For some CLA/INS combinations they reader may consider itself the addressed unit and therefore not pass it to the card at all.

Answer (score 0):

are you using Athena?

if this is the case try p2= A0

Comment: Please explain why that would help (only) in that case.

Comment: it's a vendor specific, if you map from P2 from 00 to FF you will see that  SW1 and SW2 have valid values only with P2=

            //A0 has 7 trys
            //82 has 3 trys
            //81 has 0 trys

and this works for me
[0x00, 0x20, 0, 0xa0, 4, 0x31, 0x30, 0x36, 0x31]

the pin is 1061

Comment: Please [edit] to improve your answer by adding that explanation. Consider consulting [answer].